# Why access denied for user within permitted group?

Tags: windows-8, permissions, file-permissions, uac

First let me start off by saying that I'm not an IT expert, and I've just been experimenting a lot lately with sharing and permissions in Windows 8.1. I've reached a point of extreme confusion right now and I can't find anything online.

Since I'm not running a professional edition of Windows 8.1, I've had to use the *net LOCALGROUP* command in the command prompt to add users to groups etc.

I basically made a *LOCALGROUP* called *HomeSecure*, and added two users (*AdminOne* and *AdminTwo*) to it. Both of these users are also in the *Administrators* group and are indeed administrator accounts in Windows. It sounds pointless but it's because I'm attempting to manually simulate HomeGroup functionality, and plan to add non-administrator accounts from other workstations using the *net GROUP* command instead once I've got the basics.

I have checked, and the commands worked just fine. The administrator accounts are in that group. The confusion comes about when I remove absolutely all user and group permissions (including *Everyone*) from my C:\Users\AdminOne and C:\Users\AdminTwo folders except *Administrators* and *SYSTEM*, then proceed to add allow permissions for the *HomeSecure* group...

All of the groups I gave Full Control of the folders to. I went into the advanced settings and made sure everything was checked, and even made the *HomeSecure* group take ownership of the folders. It's also worth mentioning that I made all of the child objects inherit the owners and permissions of these folders.

But even after all of that, I still can't access the above folders from the network using *HomeSecure* members. I also can't access them straight from C:\ without it prompting me for administrative consent.

Accessing via the network, I get: *You do not have permission to access ----- Contact your network administrator to request access.*

Accessing via C:\, I get: *You currently don't have permission to access this folder. Click continue to permanently get access to this folder.*

If I press continue, all that Windows does is add allow permissions for the current user (*AdminOne* or *AdminTwo*) which seems redundant because they were already allowed? They were already allowed via the *HomeSecure* permissions?

Why? Shouldn't *AdminOne* and *AdminTwo* be allowed to access both folders normally since they are in the *HomeSecure* group?

Comment: I think some screen shots would be really useful here. Windows permissions can be a bit of a black art, especially on home systems. Did you restart all the computers after the change?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few you're probably running into here:

#### Token update

Group memberships are stored in the user's token, copies of which are attached to each process running as that user. Run `whoami /all` in a command prompt to see what groups appear in your token. The one attached to the `whoami` process will be the one inherited from `cmd`, which is inherited from `explorer`. If the group membership does not appear, you need to log off and back on. Then, Windows will recognize that you are indeed a member of an appropriate group, and will let you do things that the group is allowed to do.

#### Share permissions

When sharing files through Windows shares, there are two access control lists that the user has to pass. First is the ACL on the share itself (not the folder). You can access this ACL by clicking the Permissions button in the shared folder's advanced sharing settings. The normal file system ACL is then checked. If either ACL has a deny entry for the user or one of its groups, the operation is denied. If either ACL has no relevant entry for the user or its groups, the operation is denied.

#### UAC

Note that membership in powerful default groups like Administrators is ignored for network shares that are not part of domains unless you turn UAC off. Also, if Explorer is not running elevated, it will prompt you for admin credentials if you try to navigate to a folder that only Administrators can get into.

Comment: Although I had this problem quite a while ago, I have a feeling that my issue had something to do with tokens not being updated. If not it could definitely be UAC. These days I'm running Windows 10 Home, but I presume not too much has changed in relation to this problem. I'll comment back my results once I get the time to test.